# ActiveRecord::Relation create vs find_or_create_by

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I've got the following model:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :date, :my_type, presence: true
  validates_uniqueness_of :my_type, scope: :date

  enum my_type: {
    "first_type": 1,
    "second_type": 2
  }

end
```

I'd like to create a new instance of the model and save it to the db:

```
MyModel.create!(
  date: 1.day.ago,
  type: :first_type,
  value: 1.50
)
```

The method above lets me use the enum to fill in the type, however I'd like to use the `find_or_create_by!` method to ensure, that no error will happen in case of a duplicate.

I tried doing (it fails):

```
myModel = MyModel.find_or_create_by!(
  date: 1.day.ago, 
  type: :first_type, 
  value: 1.50
)
```

I found out that I can do it this way:

```
myModel = MyModel.find_or_create_by!(
  date: 1.day.ago, 
  type: MyModel.my_types[:first_type], 
  value: 1.50
)
```

It doesn't look good though.

Why isn't it possible to use it in the same way as in the create method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find_or_create_by` quite simply first tries to `find_by` the arguments and if it cannot, passes them right along to `create`.

Meaning that the problem isn't with `create`, but rather in `find_by`.  The conversion between symbol/string and integer that `enum` provides happens when getting/setting attributes on the model, which `find_by` does not do.  `find_by` is simply not aware of the functionality provided by `enum`.

Your second method above is a decent way of accomplishing what you want.  If pretty concerns you (and long method names don't) you could always wrap it in something like:

```
def self.find_or_create_by_with_my_type(type, hash)    
  find_or_create_by hash.merge(my_type: my_types[type])
end
```